# How to format FlexJSON for emberjs

Tags: ember.js, flexjson

Hi I'm pretty new to both FlexJson and emberjs.

According to the ember guides, ember requires json in the following format:

```
{
  "post": {
      "comments": [1, 2, 3]
  }
}
```

I'm using the following for a particular model:

```
public static JSONSerializer licence = new JSONSerializer()
    .exclude("class")
    .exclude("persistent")
    .exclude("entityId")
    .rootName("licence")
    .include("licenceFeatures.id")
    .exclude("licenceFeatures.*");
```

And I'm getting the following output:

```
{
    "licence": {
        "id": 1,
        "licenceDescription": "GPL is the most widely used free software license and has a strong copyleft requirement. When distributing derived works, the source code of the work must be made available under the same license.",
        "licenceFeatures": [
            {
                "id": 15
            },
            {
                "id": 3
            }
        ],
        "licenceName": "GNU General Public License (GPL) 2.0",
        "licenceURL": "http://opensource.org/licenses/GPL-2.0"
    }
}
```

How do I format the "licenceFeatures" array  in the form ember expects?

Comment: Ember doesn't require the data in that format, Ember Data does.  Are you using Ember Data?

Comment: Yes I'm using Ember Data, is there a way with flexjson to achieve this?